# Undefined offset

Tags: php

Что может вызвать данную ошибку? 
Код

```
    $i=0;
if(count($_FILES['filesToUpload'])) {
    ini_set('display_errors',1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
    foreach ($_FILES['filesToUpload'] as $file) {

        8 строка - $bla = move_uploaded_file($file[$i], '/public/materials/image.jpg');

    10я echo $file[$i];
        $i++;
        if ($bla) {
            echo "kyaf";
        }
        else {
            echo "no";
        }
    }
}
```

При загрузке двух картинок получаю данную ошибку.

```
Notice: Undefined offset: 2 in upload-page.php on line 8

Notice: Undefined offset: 2 in upload-page.php on line 10

Notice: Undefined offset: 3 in upload-page.php on line 8

Notice: Undefined offset: 3 in upload-page.php on line 10

Notice: Undefined offset: 4 in upload-page.php on line 8

Notice: Undefined offset: 4 in upload-page.php on line 10
```

8 и 10 строки отмечены.

html часть

```
<form method="post" action="upload-page.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <input name="filesToUpload[]" id="filesToUpload" type="file" multiple="multiple" />
  <input type="submit" name="Stexelnkarnery.">
</form>
<script type="text/javascript">
    //get the input and UL list
var input = document.getElementById('filesToUpload');
var list = document.getElementById('fileList');

//empty list for now...
while (list.hasChildNodes()) {
    list.removeChild(ul.firstChild);
}

//for every file...
for (var x = 0; x < input.files.length; x++) {
    //add to list
    var li = document.createElement('li');
    li.innerHTML = 'File ' + (x + 1) + ':  ' + input.files[x].name;
    list.append(li);
}
</script>
введите сюда код
```

Comment: в тексте ошибки долно быть название файла и строка. Вы хотите, чтобы мы угадали?

Comment: Ой, я не указал, прошу прощения) Поправил пост.

Comment: У вас мне кажется направильные инднксы массивом, посмотрите тут - https://www.php.net/manual/ru/features.file-upload.multiple.php

Comment: вы уверены что привели весь код?

Comment: Имеется еще html часть, добавил в пост.

Comment: Вы пытаетесь загрузить две картинки, а код хочет загрузить пять и три из них не находит. PS. Впервые вижу, чтобы комментариями не поясняли код, а портили :D

Comment: Как можно сделать чтобы он не просил 5 картинок, а скидывал столько сколько мы ему даем?

Comment: А не должно  $file[$i] быть $file['tmp_name]'][$i]  ?

Comment: Полный ответ , и полное решение доступно тут. https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1021079/php-undefined-index