# php undefined index

Tags: php

```
    $i=0;
if(count($_FILES['filesToUpload'])) {
    ini_set('display_errors',1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
    foreach ($_FILES['filesToUpload'] as $file) {
        [7] $filename = $_FILES[[$file[$i]]['name']];
        [8 ]$bla = move_uploaded_file($_FILES[[$file[$i]]['tmp_name']], '/public/materials/'. $filename);

        // echo $file[$i];
        $i++;
        if ($bla) {
            echo "kyaf";
        }
        else {
            echo "no<br>";
        }
    }
}
```

Имеем ошибку

```
  Notice: Undefined index: name in upload-page.php on line 7

Notice: Undefined index: in on line 7

Notice: Undefined index: tmp_name in  on line 8

Notice: Undefined index: in  on line 8
```

Из за чего наблюдается данная ошибка ?

Comment: Думаю, из-за того, что кто-то не знает синтаксиса обращения к элементам массива. `$_FILES[['name'][$file[$i]]]` - это как?

Comment: Менял для проверки, теперь все на правильных местах получаю ошибки типа

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ini_set('display_errors',1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);

if(isset($_FILES['filesToUpload']['name']) 
   and ($count = count($_FILES['filesToUpload']['name'])) {

    for($i=0; $i < $count; $i++) {
       $filename = $_FILES['filesToUpload']['name'][$i];
       $bla = move_uploaded_file($_FILES['filesToUpload']['tmp_name'][$i], 'public/materials/'. $filename);
        if ($bla) {
            echo "kyaf";
        }
        else {
            echo "no<br>";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: А неужели не надо когда пишем $_FILES['name'][$i], вместе с [$i] писать и $file[$i] ? Обясните пожалуйста, почему вы так написали?

Comment: вы ходили по ссылке, которую я вам привел? Там написано - $_FILES['userfile']['name'][0] ,  $_FILES['userfile']['name'][1] -

Comment: не понимаю почему но получил unexpected ; на строке с if.

Comment: точку с запятой не стер. поправил

Comment: Не в точке с запятой проблема

Comment: Когда убераю точку с запятой, появляется unexpected =

Comment: поправил уже. пробуйте

Comment: Получаю снова эти же ошибки . но уже в бесконечном формате

Comment: print_r($_FILES['filesToUpload']);

Comment: Дело в том что цикл бесконечный. После очередного цикла, сервер просто рухнул и сайт не открывается ) . 
print_r показывал аррай с именами файлов .

Comment: да, это я виноват, там долно быть так - `$count = count($_FILES['filesToUpload']['name'])`

Comment: Бесконечность цикла ушла, но undefined index ошибки остались)

Comment: тогда хорошо б посмотреть содержимое массива  print_r($_FILES['filesToUpload']);

Comment: Array ( [name] => Array ( [0] => title1.jpg [1] => title2,jpg.jpg [2] => title3.jpg [3] => лого - копия.jpg [4] => лого.jpg ) [type] => Array ( [0] => image/jpeg [1] => image/jpeg [2] => image/jpeg [3] => image/jpeg [4] => image/jpeg ) [tmp_name] => Array ( [0] => /tmp/phpwJ40D0 [1] => /tmp/phpdI8M6X [2] => /tmp/phpcW4AzV [3] => /tmp/php03Sq2S [4] => /tmp/phpFRfhvQ ) [error] => Array ( [0] => 0 [1] => 0 [2] => 0 [3] => 0 [4] => 0 ) [size] => Array ( [0] => 110040 [1] => 115532 [2] => 114302 [3] => 24160 [4] => 24160 ) )  
Вот содержимое print_r

Comment: пробуйте сейчас

Comment: Получил 2 варнинга за одну картинку. 
Warning: move_uploaded_file(/public/materials/title1.jpg): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in upload-page.php on line 9
Warning: move_uploaded_file(): Unable to move '/tmp/phpz5Jjq5' to '/public/materials/title1.jpg' in upload-page.php on line 9
no

Comment: вот это неправильный путь для записи '/public/materials/'. $filename  - это должен быть абсолютный путь на сервере

Comment: или относительно скрипта, тогда без ведущего слэща -  'public/materials/'. $filename

Comment: Убрал / в начале пути, все получилось, не могу просто словами описать ту помощь которую вы мне оказали, респект + 500000